# How to check against a list of values in an IF statement?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to write an IF statement like this:

```
if var [is any of 1,4,5,6,12] then do stuff
```

But I don't know the syntax for this in VBA, other than:

```
if var=1 or var=4 or var=5...
```

which seems a bit clumsy. Is there a different way?

Comment: use a `select case` statement

Comment: @psychicebola does this statement also have a negation to it ? something like "else" ? Or the equivalent of "not in"...?

Comment: i updated my answer code

Comment: if your question is answered please don't forget to set the tick at the correct answer.

Comment: "else" does not seem to be working here

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/select-case-statement) statement:

```
select case var
case 1,4,5,6,12
  'do something
case else
  'alternative
end select
```

Comment: The ELSE statement is not working unless inside an IF statement

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit late to the 'party' but how about:

```
If InStr(1, ",1,5,8", "," & lVal1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

to check if 'lVal1' to equal to 1, 5 or 8.

And

```
If InStr(1, ",6,8,10,12", "," & lVal2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

to check that 'lVal2' is not equal to 6, 8, 10, 12.

The comma delimiters are important because, without them, in the first example, '15' or '58' or '158' would all be matched if 'lVal' was able to take one of those values.

You will need to pay attention to the delimiter that you use if there was likely to be any ambiguity with the value being checked for.

Likewise, using your knowledge of the range of values that will be encountered, the clunkiness of the leading delimiter in the first string and concatenating the delimiter to the front of the search value, could be removed.

Comment: ////  This is a nice and good solution that I use often, but be wary of these two items:
1) The list of valid number should be separated by comma(s) on BOTH ends...such as ",1,4,5,8,"
2) The 'lVal' also needs to be surrounded by comma(s)...such as "," & lVal & ",".
This is to prevent the 'lVal' being ",18" being found when the list of valid-numbers is ",180,187,"

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of numbers, and then in a for-loop to compare these:

```
dim newNumber as Integer
dim compareList as new List Of(int)

for count as integer = 0 to compareList.count - 1
    if newNumber = compareList(nCount)
       'Do Stuff
    end if
next
```

This is a simple way of doing that I like to do, but may get performance intensive if your lists are really large/you want to do a lot of code in the "if" loop.